# useSelector getting default state on socket.io events

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, socket.io, redux-toolkit

I am creating an online game using socket.io and Reactjs. I am using redux toolkit to store state. There, I have 2 slices: one for auth, and one for in-game data (e.g. roomId, socketId). Flipping cards is the main game mechanic.
To listen to socket.io events, I am using an useEffect function. Here is the simplfied code:

```
const stateRoom = useSelector((state) => state.game.status.currentRoom);
const stateSocketId = useSelector((state) => state.game.status.socketId);
const stateUsername = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user.username);
console.log(
      " Re-render: ", "stateRoom: ",stateRoom, "stateSocketId: ",stateSocketId, "stateUsername: ",stateUsername
    );
const cardFlippedHandler = (data) => {
    console.log(
      " Data: ", "stateRoom: ",stateRoom, "stateSocketId: ",stateSocketId, "stateUsername: ",stateUsername
    );
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("card_flipped", cardFlippedHandler);
    return () => {
      socket.off("card_flipped", cardFlippedHandler);
    };
  }, [socket]);
```

When clicking on a card, an event is emitted to the server, with the room id, then the server emit the *card_flipped* event to the clients in the room. Code on server:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
socket.on("flip_card", (data) => {
    io.to(data.room).emit("card_flipped", data);
  });
}
```

So initially, when the cards load, I am getting this log:

`Re-render:  stateRoom: myroom stateSocketId:  -_a2DG64ljS3Kl-VAAAf stateUsername: John`

A. But when I click on one of the cards, I only get:
`stateRoom: <empty string> stateSocketId: <empty string> stateUsername: John`

I tried changing the default state of the room in the slice to be the string "default", and that is what I got in the log (stateRoom: default).

B. But THEN, I created a button, that onClick, calls the same function called on event, which is cardFlippedHandler. This is what I got:

`Data: stateRoom: myroom stateSocketId: -_a2DG64ljS3Kl-VAAAf stateUsername: John`

So there is:

1. Why in A, the state in the auth slice was logged correctly, but the default one was logged in the game slice?
2. Why is that behavior happening in B?

I would appreciate any insights :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a classic example of a "stale closure" problem.

The `useEffect` and `socket.on()` calls only run *once*, on the first render.  That means that the copy of `cardFlippedHandler`  that they refer to is also the one that was created during that first render... *before* the socket connection has actually been established.  So, inside of `cardFlippedHandler`, it's still pointing to a `stateSocketId` variable that is empty.

There's a few ways to rearrange the logic to address this, but that's the core issue.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was! After going more in depth about scopes, closures, and stale closures, I fixed it by adding these variables (stateRoom, stateSocketId) to the dependency array of the useEffect, and it works perfectly now. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it by wrapping redux states in ref.

```
const Game = useSelector((state) => state.game);
let ReduxStates = useRef(Game);

React.useEffect(() => {
 ReduxStates.current = Game;
}, [Game]);
```

Use ReduxState ref in your socket listener.